# I want to put factor scores of different indicators in a data frame for factor score path analysis

Tags: r, covariance, factor-analysis, covariance-matrix

I am doing factor score path analysis

I am doing factor score path analysis for a latent variable and so I did factor score analysis to generate factor scores. Now I want to generate a variance-covariance matrix so I want to put the factor scores I generated to a data frame to be able to do so. The thing is the indicators and my arguments imply differing number of rows.

```
covfactorscore<-data.frame(bcscores$scores,dvscores$scores,fcscores$scores,infoscores$scores,scscores$scores,soscores$scores,vsscores$scores)
```

> Error in data.frame(bcscores$scores, dvscores$scores, fcscores$scores,
>   :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 101, 102, 99, 103, 104,
>   100

May anyone help me how do I go about this? Thank you

Comment: Not really an answer, but since Factor Score Path Analysis was introduced by Yves Rosseel, the creator of lavaan, maybe check his slides on this matter: https://www.uni-bielefeld.de/soz/personen/reinecke/wg_sem/2018/SEM2018_pres7_Rosseel.pdf

Comment: `length(bcscores$scores)` is 101, `length(dvscores$scores)` is 102 and so on. As lengths of every vector is different it is not able to create the dataframe and giving you the error message. If you expected their lengths to be the same, you might need to check why they were different. You might also want to read on [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: thank you guys so much. now i found the reason why they were different and it has worked now. and i will also read the slides @Clau